# jquery focus() just focusing to first text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a HTML file included multi forms. I'm trying to focus first element of the 2nd form on page loaded. I was added jquery code to end of HTML to focus first input of the form:

```
<script>
    $("form[id=form2]").find("input[type!=hidden]:first").focus();
</script>
```

It works well if first element of the 2nd form is text input, but it is not working if its dropdown or checkbox. How can I make this focus to any first element?

EDIT: I need to use ID in form selector, because of the form ID can be variable.

Comment: Pull down menu = dropdown list? Then it's a select, not input.

Comment: Yes, I meant dropdown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("form:eq(1) :input[type!='hidden']").first().focus();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/m69h5ukf/)

Don't use the attributes selector with ID's, just using the ID selector is much faster.
You can use the `:input` selector, it selects all input elements, like input, textarea, select and button.
Then use either `:first` or `first()` to get the first one.

**EDIT:** based on the comment, the ID is not constant, so using the tagName and `:eq()` you can select the second form, and as `:eq()` is zero based, the second one would be `1`

Comment: But form id is not constant.

Comment: Then you should probably lead with that in the question. Will it always be the second the form on the page.

Answer (score 3):

The :input selector finds any valid form input element, which incluses dropdown lists and checkboxes, according to its documentation at http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/.
Since it looks like it also includes hidden fields, I've also added the :visible selector to excluse hidden form elements.

```
<script>
    $("form[id=form2]").find(":input:visible:first").focus();
</script>
```

Comment: From documentation: Selects all input, textarea, **select** and button elements (http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)

Comment: This however does not account for not finding hidden inputs.

Comment: Why not, @DerekS? Hidden inputs are still inputs.

Comment: Updated my answer to exclude hidden fields and added documentation link for :input selector

Comment: @CaseyFalk, yes, but OP wants to exclude not include them.

Comment: Ahh... Didn't catch the update. Thanks @RemcovanDalen.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer and comments. Answer is worked, but I think, neither mine nor your way is programmatically well. Because of this I am walking with adeneo's answer.